# IE6 load img using Accordion jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, image, load, internet-explorer-6, accordion

In IE6 only, using Accordion jQuery plugin to open a DIV element, all img elements (backgrounds too) inside the DIV are loaded on each click, to open or close the chosen element.

Example:

There are 10 closed DIVs, you click on the 2nd one to open it, you can see in the status bar the requests to load all img elements inside the 10 DIVs, you click to close it and do it again. If you do it for 2 or 3 DIVs it even can lock the page.

How is managed img elements loading not displayed elements by css?
If i pre-load img, it's the same thing

No problem in Firefox or IE7, IE8

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your code, that should do the trick:

```
if ($.browser.msie) { 
    document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache", false, true); 
}
```

The problem lies with the fact the Accordion use background images for which IE6 as problem with the cache settings. You can browse on the web for more info on this.

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings. It sounds like you're using the typical developer setting to load pages "every time i visit the page", which make IE6 redownload the images every time. Your standard users will have the setting "automatically", which will mitigate this error.